# I am getting results different while using #defines

Tags: c

I am working in a project where we have lots of memory as #defines
such as

```
#define SRAM1      0xb0000000+((1024*1024)-64)   //1
```

I was getting an error if I use above #define
If I change this to

```
#define SRAM1     (0xb0000000+((1024*1024)-64))  //2
```

It works.
Even this works

```
#define SRAM1      0xb0000000+((1048576)-64)     //3
```

Is it a problem with associativity or multiplication in pointer is not allowed in this way?
P.S
usage in our work is

```
         if((*(OSLongType *)(SRAM1)) == 1)
```

or

```
         *(OSLongType *)(SRAM1)= 0;
```

in this way.

Comment: What error are you getting for the first one?

Comment: Please add the code that actually uses this macro

Comment: `#define`statements are literal text replacements used as syntactic sugar, we can't determine why this is happening without the code using this.

Comment: It is much safer to enclose macro constants such as these in parentheses, as in your variation (2), for otherwise you can run into problems with operator precedence.  Remember always that macros are not variables.

Comment: You really need to create a minimal but complete and compilable example that still shows the problem.

Comment: I can put lines where it is used exactly. This #define is not used in more than one file.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a blind shot since you didn't provide the code that uses the `#define`, but you are violating one of the fundamental best practices about constants in `#define`s.

Since `#define`s are applied as a blind text replacement, if you don't surround calculations with parentheses you are potentially making a mess of the expressions of code that uses your define. Consider

```
#define SEVEN 5+2
```

and then someone using it as

```
printf("thirty-five: %d", SEVEN*5);
```

This will actually print 15, as it will be replaced as:

```
printf("thirty-five: %d", 5+2*5);
```

So, to avoid problems always surround your constant defines with parentheses. Why the last one seems to work is behind me, maybe you didn't actually recompile with it?

Comment: This kind of code is not used in more than two files. I checked if such problem is there, but everywhere the #define is covered in parantheses, without any multiplication you have shown.

Comment: I compiled and checked binaries time of build before flashing.

Comment: Nitpick: it'll actually print 15 ;)

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe your claim that variation (2) produces the behavior you expect but (1) and (3) produce different behavior than each other. Furthermore, if indeed you were using the macro as you describe:

```
*(OSLongType *)(SRAM1)= 0;
```

then you would not see any difference in behavior between (1) and (2).

I'm inclined to suppose that what you actually had a problem with was instead along the lines of

```
*(OSLongType *)SRAM1= 0;
```

That has different meaning with your variations (1) and (3) than with your variation (2).  With variation (1), for example, it expands to

```
*(OSLongType *)0xb0000000+((1024*1024)-64)= 0;
```

.  The cast and indirection operators have higher precedence than does `+`, so that's equivalent to

```
(*((OSLongType *)0xb0000000)) + ((1024*1024) - 64) = 0;
```

.  That won't compile because the left-hand side of the assignment is not an lvalue.  Variation (3) does not solve this problem.

With variation (2), however, the expression expands instead to ...

```
*(OSLongType *)(0xb0000000+((1024*1024)-64))= 0;
```

... which is perfectly valid.  The address is computed as an integer, then converted to a pointer, then dereferenced.  The result of the conversion is implementation defined, but the code should at least compile, and it may do what you want.

The only possible difference between variations (1) and (3) is the data types chosen for the integer constants.  The constant `1024` definitely has type `int`, and the expression `1024*1024` therefore also has type `int`.  If your system's `int`s are only 16 bits wide, however, then the arithmetic product of 1024 and 1024 does not fit in a 16-bit integer.  In that case, the resulting value of that expression is implementation-defined, and definitely not 1048576.  In that case, however, the constant `1048676` represents a valid value of type `long int`, making (3) different from (1).

**Updated to add:**

I would recommend consistently using this form:

```
#define SRAM1     (0xb0000000+(((uintptr_t)1024*1024)-64))
```

Type `uintptr_t` is defined in `stdint.h`, which you will therefore need to include if you do not do so already.  You could throw in some more casts to `uintptr_t` if you are comforted by such consistency, but they are not necessary.

Comment: I had to delete my earlier comment under the other answer, which said "but OP's code failed *with* parentheses", because the question is poorly worded and I think there is a full-stop missing on his third line. But I agree with you, how can his last example work if the first doesn't?

Comment: I will talk to my lead. Show him the code and ask for clarification. I will also put a simpler version of code that I am using. It is a big project, and giving context is not that easy but I can make sure that the code piece I have written is fully correct with my comments wherever I made.